# error when using multiple EF migrations / configurations (__MigrationHistory is recreated everytime)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

i have 2 different and indipendent dbcontexts and i want to create the db schema (using npgsql/posgresql) with code first migration.
i put in 2 different folder the configurations (with AutomaticMigrationsEnabled set to false) and the 2 initial migration files (once for every dbcontext) using the Add-Migration command line tool.

then i use the command line Update-Database with the first configuration and it works, the db is correctly created with the tables related to the first context.
But when i try to use Update-Database with the other configuration i get an exception because it is trying to create the table __MigrationHistory that already exists.

what's wrong in my code?

Comment: This might help http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx might help as well. If you share the exact commands you're using on the command line, that might help in figuring out the problem, though I wonder if this is an npgsql specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the error, i don't  know if it's a bug of entityframework or npgsql dll but if the dbcontexts use a schema different from dbo (i have all the schema set to 'public', the default postgresql s name) it's necessary to set the same schema also for the history table subclassing the HistoryContext https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx.

the detailed error is that the pseudo code executed bu the migration is

```
if not exist the table 'dbo'.__MigrationHistory
create the table 'public'.__MigrationHistory
```